# Which is the best scenario for use IdentityServer?

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

In what situation it is best to use `IdentityServer` instead of `Identity` with permission with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization`?

Where it is best to use one over the other?

I choose `IdentityServer` for speed reasons or for what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You choose IdentityServer because you want SSO for your different applications or clients (mobile applications/web applications/services/apis etc). IdentityServer also allows you to separate your authentication and authorization concerns from your other applications.

Asp.Net Identity is just the built in membership system for Asp.Net (user accounts and managing them). Asp.Net Identity can be used in conjunction with IdentityServer pretty seamlessly.